How do we interpret the values of face_face_adjacency_matrix in pymeshlab?
I am using pymeshlab for a project where I would like to know the list of faces adjacent to a given one. I have seen the face_face_adjacent_matrix but it is a data structure I do not understand how it works. For each face, one entry like the one on the list below is given:
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])


I just do not know how to interpret these values. Any clues?
I could not find any examples of its use. I expected these could identify the possible three neighboring faces of a given face on a 3D mesh.

It was a bug: github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/PyMeshLab/issues/375
